# Custom post type permalink uses archive page to display posts

Tags: custom-post-types, archive-template

I can't figure out why my custom post type page template uses the archive page to display posts. I'm pretty sure I have the right files. These are the important files, regarding this issue, in my root folder:

**Root**

```
mytheme
- archive.php
- home.php
- single.php
- team.php
- single-team.php
- archive-team.php
```

**Usage**

```
 1. team.php is a custom page template. All team members are shown here.
 2. single-team.php displays a single team member.
```

**My Post Type**

```
 function create_post_type_team() { register_post_type( 'team',
   array(
       'labels' => array(
       'name' => __( 'Team' ),
       'singular_name' => __( 'Team' )
      ),
   'public' => true,
   'has_archive' => true,
   'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ),
   'taxonomies' => array('post_tag') 
    )
  );
}

add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_team' );
```

**My Problem**

When I visit mysite/team (team.php), the page is using archive-team.php to display posts. It should use team.php which is assigned to the page as page template via the admin panel. The weird thing is that when I change the page url from /team to /team2, it does use team.php and not archive-team.php.

**Notes**

Before this problem occurred, mysite/team/member (single-team.php) was not working. I went to my permalink settings - did nothing - and went back. From this point mysite/team/member worked, but team.php started using archive-team.php. If I set has_arhive => false, it falls back to home.php.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the code you have in `team.php` to `archive-team.php`. Also, read [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Template_Files).

By default, Wordpress matches the id of the custom post type to a file with the name archive-{custom_post_type_id}.php, and if it doesn't exist it uses the archive.php file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does work, but now I have duplicated code in team.php and archive-team.php. I still need team.php to assigned the post type to a page. Is that good practice?

Comment: Your function to register the custom post type is in the team.php file? A good practice would be to have that function in functions.php of your theme or to create a plugin and add it there (what I recommend). Anyway

Comment: No no, my function is in functions.php. I'm trying to say that my team.php code and archive-team.php code are the exact same files now. That feels strange to me, but i'll leave that for what it is. Thanks.